# Hibernate orphan removal doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate

can someone explain me why the orphan removal property doesn't work in the following sample code? The very last check in the test fails... At the end of the test, the database contains the parent and the child but the relationship between them is gone. So the child is really orphan but still not cleared.

```
public class ParentDao3Test {
    @Autowired private ParentDao parentDao;
    @Autowired private ChildDao childDao;

    @Test
    public void testCRUD() {
        DBChild child = new DBChild("John");
        DBParent parent = new DBParent();
        parent.addChild(child);

        parentDao.persist(parent);

        assertTrue(parent.getId() > 0);
        assertTrue(parent.getChilds().size() == 1);
        assertTrue(child.getId() > 0);

        parent.removeChild(child);

        parentDao.flush(); 

        //succeed
        assertTrue(parent.getChilds().size() == 0);  

        //fail here because the child doesn't get cleared from the DB    
        assertNull(childDao.findById(child.getId())); 

    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
public class DBParent {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(nullable=true)
    @JoinTable
    private Set<DBChild> childs = new HashSet<DBChild>();

    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    @Version
    private Integer version;

    public void addChild(DBChild child) {
        this.childs.add(child);
    }

    public void removeChild(DBChild child) {
        this.childs.remove(child);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class DBChild {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private long id;

    @Column(name="name", nullable = false, length=1024)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    @Version
    private Integer version;
}
```

**Workaround :**
By adding a flush just after the persist seems to make the test to pass. Basically it seems that, as long as the relationship is not flushed into the database, the orphan removal property doesn't seem to work. This make me think that the orphan removal doesn't work on the 1st level cache.